# PHP: fopen can't create file on servers public_html

Tags: php

on my localhost my script generates a file that does not exist and everything seems to work. now i have uploaded script on the server. i been trying to create a file on the servers public html. but `fopen` cannot create the file

```
$file = '/home/mysite/public_html/contacts.xml';
chmod($file, 0777);
if(!($f = fopen($file, "w"))){
 echo "error openning file<br />"; 
}
```

I always  get 'error openning file'.

Comment: is `/home/mysite/public_html/contacts.xml` the absolute path to the file on the server? The file path on your server will be different to your localhost.

Comment: yes its the absolute path. i don't know why its not working but on `mysite2` its working

Comment: It may well be '/home/mysite/public_html/' on your local machine, but it will be completely different on your server. try echoing `getcwd()` and you will see that your server has a different file structure.

Comment: in my local using xampp. its `C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/`
on server its  `/home/mysite/public_html/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must set the chmod 777 via FTP or web administration interface of your webserver for security is not possible to set via PHP

Comment: should i set public_html?

Comment: is possible but not recommended.
create some folder and then set your chmod to 777
security for some webservers disable chmod rw to public_html

Comment: There has to be a better way than making a publicly-accessible directory world-writable. Like maybe assigning a group to the apache user, to permit it to write.